# ~m, s and () in perl regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get hold of regular expressions in Perl. Can anyone please provide any examples of what matches and what doesn't for the below regular expression?

```
$sentence =~m/.+\/(.+)/s
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=~` is the binding operator; it makes the regex match be performed on `$sentence` instead of the default `$_`.  `m` is the match operator; it is optional (e.g. `$foo =~ /bar/`) when the regex is delimited by `/` characters but required if you want to use a different delimiter.
`s` is a regex flag that makes `.` in the regex match any characters; by default `.` does not match newlines.

The actual regex is `.+\/(.+)`; this will match one or more characters, then a literal `/` character, then one or more other characters.  Because the initial `.+` consumes as much as possible while still allowing the regex to succeed, it will match up to the last `/` in the string that has at least one character after it; then the `(.+)` will capture the characters that follow that `/` and make them available as `$1`.

So it is essentially capturing the final component of a filepath.  Of `foo/bar` it will capture the `bar`, of `foo/bar/` it will capture the `bar/`.  Strings with only one component, like `/foo` or `bar/` or `baz` will not match.

Answer (score 1):

Any string, including multi-line strings, that contain a slash character somewhere in the middle of the string.

Matches:

```
 foo/bar
 asdf\nwrqwer/wrqwerqw           # /s modifier allows '.' to match newlines
```

Doesn't match:

```
 asdfasfdasf                     # no slash character
 /asdfasdf                       # no characters before the slash
 asdfasf/                        # no characters after the slash
```

In addition, the entire substring that follows the last slash in the string will be captured and assigned to the variable `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Breakdown:

- `$sentence =~` — match `$sentence` with
- `m/` — the pattern consisting of
- `.` — any character
- `+` — one or more times
- `\/` — then a forward-slash
- `(` — and, saving in the `$1` capture group,
- `.+` — any character one or more times
- `)`
- `/s` — allowing `.` to match newlines

See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for information about operators such as `=~` and [quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) such as `m//`, and [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) about regular expressions and their options such as `/s`.